# How to let a div overflow in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a static website from HTML and CSS.

What I want is I have a div oversized such that even the screen size goes down, it overflows and gets out of the screen having an oversized kind of effect.

Also, I have set the `position: absolute` so that it gets out of the flow, that's not a problem till now (providing this information so that maybe this can be the problem)

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="background-title">Adarsh Dubey</div>
```

**My CSS:*

```
.background-title {
  font-size: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-2%, -13%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: Proper overflowed]

The picture above shows the overflow kind of effect, which is fine. But notice that I'm in dev tools and the screen size is `1920px`.

[image: No Overflow Image]

Now when I go screen size of around `1200px`, the `.background-title` doesn't overflow but instead, it just allows the user to see horizontal scrollbar. What I want is that to get out from the screen so it looks really big.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the browser how big you want the box, otherwise it will keep expanding.

You can either set a `width`, or set the `right` property.

```css
.background-title {
  font-size: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-2%, -13%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer for this problem is to set the `overflow` property to `hidden` on `body` and set width to 100%.

In this way the body will remain at 100% and the overflowed content in it will be hidden

Answer (score 1):

you have to use **@media** for particular screen where your text is oveflow

```css
.background-title {
  font-size: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translate(-2%, -13%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
      padding: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1750px) {
    .background-title {
        font-size: 250px;

    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
    .background-title {
        font-size: 200px;

    }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .background-title {
        font-size: 150px;

    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .background-title {
        font-size: 130px;

    }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .background-title {
        font-size: 100px;

    }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .background-title {
        font-size: 50px;

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="background-title">Adarsh Dubey</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easier if you use bootstrap unless you can use **media** for that issue
e.g.

```
.background-title {
  font-size: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-2%, -13%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) { // you can change the screen size to any size that you like but there are some standard sizes
.background-title {
  font-size: 80px;
}
}
```